# What is the notion of a group object and its action in a 2-category?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, simplicial-stuff, 2-categories

It is well known that a *group object* in a category $C$ (with terminal object $1$ and such that any two objects of $C$ have a product) is defined as an object $G$ in $C$ with the following morphisms:

$m:G \times G \rightarrow G$, $e:1 \rightarrow G$, $\mathit{inv}: G \rightarrow G$

satisfying some conditions modelled on the group axioms such that $m$ behaves as the multiplication map, e behaves as the identity and $\mathit{inv}$ behaves as the inverse map.

The *group action* (right) of a group object $G$ on an object $X$ in $C$ can be defined as a morphism $\rho:X \times G \rightarrow X$ in $C$ such that the following two diagrams are commutative:

[image]   [image]

where $\mathit{id}_X$, $\mathit{id}_G$ are identity morphisms at $X$ and $G$ respectively and $\mathit{pr}_1$ is the first projection on $X$ from the product $X \times 1$.

**My Question are the following:**

**(1)** What is the analogue of the above notion in a $2$-category? I couldn't find any literature in this direction.

So I tried to guess it's definition roughly in the following way:

Let $C$ be a 2-category (with terminal object $1$ and such that any two objects of $C$ have a product in the context of 2- category as mentioned in https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/2-limit#2limits_over_diagrams_of_special_shape ). I define a *group object* in the 2-category $C$ as an object $G$ with the following *1-morphisms*:

$m \in C(G \times G ,G)$, $e \in C(1,G)$, $inv \in C(G,G)$ satisfying some conditions *similar as above* but in this case every equality in the conditions will be replaced by an invertible *2-morphism* satisfying certain appropriate  coherent conditions.

Correspondingly the action of $G$ on an object $X$ in $C$ will be defined exactly in the same way but the *above two diagrams* will be commutative only upto invertible 2-morphisms.

**Is my guess correct?**

Even if it is correct but writing all the details (taking care of all the invertible 2 morphisms) seems very complicated to me and seems an *inappropriate* definition to work with.(Both in the context of strict 2-category and bicategory)

**So what should be an appropriate definition for a group object in a 2-category and its corresponding action on an object?** (Both in the context of strict 2-category and bicategory)

Secondly,

It is well known that the Strict 2-Group is a group object in **Cat**(when **Cat** is considered as a  1 -category or a usual category ).

But then

**(2)** What is the group object in **Cat** (when **Cat** is considered as strict 2-category)?

I would be also very grateful if someone can refer some literatures in this direction.

Thank you.

Comment: 4 upvotes, 4 bookmarks is a good number :D Hope some one answers your question..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I also hope that :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll have a go at answering your question (although higher category-theory is absolutely not my area of expertise).

The conditions for $(G,m,e,inv)$ to be a group object is stipulated by the following relations

1. $m\circ (e\times inv)\circ\Delta=m\circ (inv\times e)\circ\Delta=id_G$
2. $m\circ (m\times id_G)=m \circ (id_G\times m)$
3. $m\circ(e\times id_G)=m\circ(id_G\times e)=id_G$

where $\Delta$ is the diagonal map and $(e,id_G)$ is the obvious map $G\to G\times G$.

Writing these out in full is a bit pedantic but it's important. The reason for this is that we can see that adding 2-morphisms to obtain a strict 2-category *doesn't change anything* about the structure of $G$.
In particular we don't gain any structure from the 2-category case. Thus the strict 2-groups are actually group objects in $\mathbf{Cat}$ *viewed as a strict 2-category*.

There are other ideas for "group-like" things in higher categories. You can ask for things like **weak 2-groups** where we consider weak 2-categories and thus only  require the composition of morphisms to be associative and unital *up to* some 2-isomorphism. In particular a weak 2-group is a monoidal category with all morphisms invertible such that for any object $x$ we have $x\otimes x^{-1}$ and $x^{-1}\otimes x$ are only *isomoprhic* to the tensor unit 1. (This corresponds to  (1).) We can also define the notion of a ***coherent 2-group*** where we make specific choices for $x^{-1}$ and specific isomorphisms $x\otimes x^{-1}\to 1$ and 
$1\to x\otimes x^{-1}$ such that these form an adjoint pair. All of this is developed in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0307200.pdf) of Baez's & Lauda's (see definition 20).

In particular, a group object (or a strict 2-group)  in a 2-category with finite products is a coherent 2-group $G$ except the natural isomorphisms defining the "coherent structure" of $G$ are all simply the identity (see Definition 29 of the above paper).

Another reference which spells out different group-like structures in 2-categories as well as how these things act on categories $X$ is given in [this paper](https://www.emis.de/journals/TAC/volumes/30/43/30-43.pdf) by Morten's & Picken's.

**edit:**  edited for clarity (see comments below)

Comment: Why do you think " we don't gain any extra structure from the 2 category case" ? In fact when each of the equality of the conditions you mentioned is replaced by a specific choice of 2-isomorphisms and the notion of  product and terminal object is replaced by 2 product and 2 terminal object(that is they come with an isomorphism) why do you think they will not add any extra structure? Also  a strict 2 group can be seen as a 2 category with one object and invertible 1-morphisms and 2-morphisms... Then how will you describe this in this 2 category case?

Comment: @AdittyaChaudhuri I said in the case of a _strict_ 2-category we don't gain any structure for the group object. Again this is because we simply have a category enriched in categories -- however those equalities still have to hold on the nose, not just up to 2-isomorphism! As for the equivalence of the two definitions this follows from the fact that internal categories in **Grp** are equivalent to group objects in **Cat** -- this is explained well in [this short paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0212065.pdf) of Forrester-Barker's.

Comment: @AdittyaChaudhuri the point is that the structure of a group object is completely determined by conditions on the objects and 1-morphisms. When considering a strict 2-category we don't change these things at all! We merely say that we also have morphisms of 1-morphisms but this doesn't at all change the conditions for a group object.

Comment: @AdittyaChaudhuri sorry for the comment spam but you should be careful distinguishing between 2-morphisms in your strict 2-group and natural transformations of functors of categories! In particular the definition of one object with invertible 1-morphisms and 2-morphisms corresponds to a category object in **Grp**  which corresponds to a group object in **Cat** (see my first comment)

Comment: Thanks for referring to https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0307200.pdf. I have seen this paper previously also but did not notice that the answer to my question is hidden in the definition 29, in the  section Internalisation. I got your point that for saying , some "entity" is a group object in "something"  that entity need to have a representation as a category object in the category of groups. But there is no analogous description as " a 2 category object" in groups. So the closest one can get to "this sort of notion" is given in the reference I mentioned above in this comment.

Comment: For getting my answer +1 to your answer!

Comment: @AdittyaChaudhuri Note that in Definition 29 at the end they state that a strict 2-group in a 2-category is "...a group in the underlying category of this 2-category" which is what I was trying to communicate above. I'm glad you are satisfied! :)

Comment: Thanks for explaining.

Comment: For the sake of completeness of your answer can you please  add the notion of definition 29 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0307200.pdf along with the reference? Hope this will help the future readers. Thank you.

Comment: @AdittyaChaudhuri Let me know if these edits work and whether you'd like me to make any more changes. And thanks for the feedback!

Comment: It looks fine. :)

Comment: Hey @AdittyaChaudhuri! I see you unaccepted my answer. Was there a problem with it? :(

Comment: Actually I need some time to accept. As my real motive behind this question is to understand the action of "some notion of group object in a 2-category" on another 2- category. Now there exists a 2-category consists of 2-categories as objects , 2-functors as 1-morphisms and 2-nautural transformations as 2-morphisms. Now strict 2-group is a group object in  Cat and we have a notion of action of strict 2-group on a category. So a proper analogue in 2-categories should have the same properties. But I am not able to figure out properly this notion in the 2-category of 2-categories .

Comment: Lastly even if the notion you mentioned makes sense , but incase of 2 category of 2 categories it looks very complicated to me and quite complex to work with. For example in Cat  the group object is quite simple . May be I am missing something. Your answer is fine . May be the way I wrote the question was  misleading.  I may post a new question in this direction and mention the link here !

Comment: So once I am convinced about the doubt I mentioned I will accept your answer. Also it is highly appreciated if you can mention the case of 2 category of 2 categories with little explanation regarding it. Thanks!

Comment: ! I am apologising for my behaviour (first accepting and then unaccepting) and the inconvenience caused due to it.. I am again accepting your answer as my doubt is not clearly expressed through the way I asked the question here. In fact according to the question I posted, your answer is fine. So I will clearly write my doubt in details  in a  separate question and will mention the link here. Thank you.